# JUnit testing on Android application with Robolectrics framework

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I am currently working on a test project with Robolectrics in Eclipse ADT which tests against my main android application. I am using Junit 4. However, I cannot make it work. Could anyone point out any mistakes in my code. Code is follows. I am really struggling on it. Here is error trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FFFFFF

    "
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.init(ResourceLoader.java:148)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.setLayoutQualifierSearchPath(ResourceLoader.java:506)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setupApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:362)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.internalBeforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:307)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:285)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FFFFFF

    "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ColorResourceLoader.convertRawValue(ColorResourceLoader.java:44)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ColorResourceLoader.convertRawValue(ColorResourceLoader.java:9)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceReferenceResolver.processResource(ResourceReferenceResolver.java:29)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ColorResourceLoader.processNode(ColorResourceLoader.java:38)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.XpathResourceXmlLoader.processResourceXml(XpathResourceXmlLoader.java:27)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.loadResourceXmlFile(DocumentLoader.java:58)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.loadResourceXmlDir(DocumentLoader.java:52)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.loadResourceXmlDir(DocumentLoader.java:39)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.loadValueResourcesFromDir(ResourceLoader.java:233)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.loadValueResourcesFromDirs(ResourceLoader.java:227)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.loadValueResources(ResourceLoader.java:170)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.init(ResourceLoader.java:132)
    ... 19 more



   @RunWith(CustomTestRunner.class)
public class AccessActivity_Test{

    private AccessActivity activity;
     private Button signup;
     private Button signupwithFB;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        activity = new AccessActivity();
        activity.onCreate(null);
        //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        //FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.layout.access_main);
        signup= (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        signupwithFB = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_signupFB);
        //frag = Robolectric.shadowOf(activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    public void TestSignUpButton()throws Exception{

        signup.performClick();


    }

    @Test
    public void TestSignUpWithFBButton(){
        signupwithFB.performClick();

    }
```

Here is the custom TestRunner:

```
  public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public CustomTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
        addClassOrPackageToInstrument("com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity");
        addClassOrPackageToInstrument("com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity");
    }


    @Override
    protected void bindShadowClasses() {
        super.bindShadowClasses();
        Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowSherlockActivity.class);
        Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowSherlockFragmentActivity.class);
    }
 }
```

Here is the Activity:

```
public class AccessActivity extends RoboSherlockFragmentActivity {

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.access_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        getSupportActionBar().show();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.container, new AccessOptionsFragment())
              .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                    savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM,
                getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is code of the fragment:

```
public class AccessOptionsFragment extends RoboSherlockFragment implements
        AnimationListener, OnClickListener  {
    // @InjectView(tag = "logo_layout")
    // LinearLayout logo_layout;
    // @InjectView(tag = "signup_layout")
    // LinearLayout signup_layout;
    //result codes if other than standard
    //@InjectView(tag = "signup_layout")LinearLayout signup_layout;

    public final static int LOGIN_REQUESTED = 1;
    public final static int SIGNUP_REQUESTED = 2;
    public final static int SIGNUPFB_REQUESTED = 3;
    public final static int SKIPACCESS_REQUESTED = 4;

    private Animation fadeInAnimation;
.....

..
```

Can anyone give me any hint of where it goes wrong? Or any one have better idea?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, is there an error?  What are the symptoms?  Also, I think the Fragment is missing some code.

Comment: The fragment is running fine in the main application. I only took some of the codes from it. I have attached the error trace in my question, Joe

Comment: Robolectric works by reimplementing the android libraries on top of java.  In some cases, the reimplementation has bugs or is incomplete.  This may be the cause of the issue you're seeing.  It looks like it's having problems loading a resource xml file.  Try to find out when xml resource file is giving it problems.  Then you can look at the [Robolectric source](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) and see if it's implemented correctly.  Also, make sure you're using the latest version of Robolectric.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Robolectric does not find the Android SDK.
Go to the run configuration of your testProject and set the Enviromnt variable to:

ANDROID_HOME = C:\your\sdk\location

That worked for me. Hope that helpes.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late, but you need to add `android.jar` to your project as an external library so that `Robolectric` can re-implement it with its `Shadow` classes.

You can find the jar file at `sdk\platforms\android-xx\android.jar`.

Comment: y u deleted ur question now ?